# Does IntelliJ or VSCode have the ability to set breakpoints that do not halt execution, instead taking a snapshot of stack/vars that you can view?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm currently on a team developing a Slack bot, we've begun the classic `console.log` debugging strategy and our log output is already getting extremely bloated.  A team lead mentioned breakpoints and I decided it would probably be a good idea to start using them but there is a problem:

Slack bots are sometimes responding to requests in a time-sensitive manner. For instance, when opening a modal you only have 3 seconds following a user action to open the modal, clearly any breakpoint that halts execution before the modal is opened would cause problems.

Thinking about it, it seems like something that /should/ be possible.  When reaching the breakpoint simply take the stack/vars that would be displayed and store/display them without halting execution.  Unfortunately, 90% of the time I think "this should exist", it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I could just google it huh?

IntelliJ - Tracepoint
VSCode - Logpoint